# Android AsyncTask Strange Compilation Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I created this simple code but didn't know what causing the compilation error

```
import java.util.List;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class TestAsyncInternalClass {
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<InternalPrivateClass>> {
        @Override
        protected List<InternalPrivateClass> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        private class InternalPrivateClass{

        }   
    }
}
```

it is giving me the following compilation error

```
InternalPrivateClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

Moving the `InternalPrivateClass` to the top class level would solve the issue 
but what is causing this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are using the `private` inner class in the template:

```
extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<InternalPrivateClass>>
```

Moving `InternalPrivateClass` out of the `AsyncTask` fixes the issue as it places it in a scope that is visible to the where `MyAsyncTask` is being defined.

If you change the above to

```
extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MyAsyncTask.InternalPrivateClass>>
```

you will get a different error stating that `InternalPrivateClass` has `private` access and is therefore inaccessible from the scope you would like to use it in.

Your two options are:

1. Move the `InnerPrivateClass` out of `MyAsyncTask`
2. Make `InnerPrivateClass` a public class and use `MyAsyncTask.InnerPrivateClass` in the template

Answer (score 1):

When you declare:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<InternalPrivateClass>>
```

`InternalPrivateClass` hasn't been declared yet and this is why the compiler show that error.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the class `InternalPrivateClass` and just add the missing import of `InternalPrivateClass`

Use the shortkey to resolve the imports.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>